# Check FTP last operations

Tags: ftp, client

Sometimes I make a bad move / missclick while using my FTP client (Transmit, OSX) and files are moved in a random directory.
Then I waste my time to find what file moved and where.

Is there a FTP command or something to check last events ?

Comment: I dont know much about the program you are using, but you should be able to enable some sort of activity log to view operations.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a command so I have not thought about something specific to my client. I checked Transmit and all my activity was logged in Window > Transcription !
If you post this as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: Glad to hear you managed! Sometimes we just need to know what to look for! Good luck further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know much about the program you are using, but you should be able to enable some sort of activity log to view operations.